# Comparing value from RFID reader to string

Tags: python

I'm trying a very simple thing - grabbing a value from an RFID reader, comparing it to a value and having it do one thing if it's the value and something else if it's not.

Here's my code:

```
"""
Continuously read.
"""

import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-AH02MAUE', 9600) # here you have to write your port. If you dont know how to find it just write ls -l /dev/tty.* in your terminal (i'm using mac)

def rfidResponse(responseID):
    print responseID
    if responseID == "750047FB76BF":
        print "This one"
    else:
        print "other one"

while True:
    try:
        response = ser.readline()
        # print response
        stringResponse = str(response)
        print stringResponse
        rfidResponse(stringResponse)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

ser.close()
```

But no matter what card I put to the RFID reader it always does the `else` - here's an example of my output (with the correct card placed over the reader):

```
7100253299FF

7100253299FF

other one

750047FB76BF

750047FB76BF

other one
```

Comment: `"7100253299FF" != "750047FB76BF"`!

Comment: Sorry fixed to show the error (same output)

Comment: What does `repr(responseID)` show?

Comment: Seems weird but nothing is output when I add `repr(responseID)` to `def rfidResponse(responseID):` (although this could be my misunderstanding of how to use `repr()`

Comment: No, I mean add `print repr(responseID)`

Comment: Sorry - I get `'\x02750047FB76BF\r\n'` and the 2nd card reads `'\x03\x027100253299FF\r\n'`

Comment: Does that answer your question, then?

Comment: It does explain why the check doesn't work, but is there a way to test against the `7100253299FF` rather than what repr() outputs? Since the repr() values seem to be more inconsistent in their formats

Comment: You will have to remove the irrelevant characters - e.g. `.strip()` to remove the whitespace (`'\r\n'`) - but I can't tell you which those are, the leading bytes could be relevant.